# What is deleteSessionCookie.jsp?

Tags: force.com-sites, community, spring14

I have a custom error page set up on my Community, and I use it to track analytics about when my community is crashing.  Each time a user hits the error page, I track the page they were trying to reach (`$Site.OriginalUrl`) and the specific error message  (`$Site.ErrorDescription`).

Ever since Spring '14 was released, I've been catching 40+ crashes a day on a page called `/communityPrefix/secur/deleteSessionCookie.jsp`.  Strangely, `ErrorDescription` is always blank - there's no error message to debug with.  In addition, I haven't heard anything from any of my users about there being crashes in the community, which is surprising for something that's happening so much.

Have you seen this before?  How can I debug and solve these crashes?

Answer (score 1):

`/secur/deleteSessionCookie.jsp` is a page whose purpose is stated in its title -- it deletes your Salesforce cookie, thereby logging you out of Salesforce.

You can try it like this:

1. Log into your Salesforce community
2. Go to `/secur/deleteSessionCookie.jsp` in a new tab
3. Reload your original tab -- you'll be asked to re-authenticate.

This answers the initial question, but doesn't explain why there have been 'page crashes' logged on this page.